# Time string to a different DateTime format in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am inserting time via this `timeDepartureArray[i] = timeDeparture.Text.ToString();`
and it is formatted as `h:mm tt` this is a string. How can I fetch again that string to turn it into a `DateTime` like `H:mm` 
EDIT:
I really don't know how to stress out my question more. That is really my question. The time I'm outputting is set to `string`, so I want to fetch that `string` and display it again as a `datetime`. How can that be so hard?

Comment: Google Google Google

Comment: Incomplete code. We don't know what you are trying to do. Post some code so we can help. Also read the FAQs about how to post good questions

Comment: please show how have you tried to solve the problem

Comment: I've already googled, there is this Convert() then DateParse(); I know there is a simple code for it somehow.

Comment: @Noobster MSDN.... search examples for date <-> string conversion/parsing.... better yet, dig up some stack overflow questions... you are bound to find your answer.... you see, you must show some research effort... and a precise question as to where you are facing difficulty... if not, brace yourself for downvotes, close votes and of course, judgmental comments like these.

Comment: I've updated my question, and for the record. I can't find here in stackoverflow what I want to do.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Assuming `timeDeparture.Text` has Format `h:mm tt` like 9:10 pm, you have to parse it first into DateTime and use `.ToString()` to bring it into the desired  24h format.

In .NET `h` is for 12h format and `H` represents 24h format.

```
string timeDeparture = "10:30 PM";
DateTime parsedResult = DateTime.ParseExact(timeDeparture, "h:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = parsedResult.ToString("H:mm"); // H for 24 hour
```

Comment: No... I didn't intend to criticize on field of that typo... It's just that these questions should best be avoided answering...

Comment: This is what I am talking about, there is an error for me for that `CultureInfo` that says it doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: @Toshi http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm look there, I understand your `HH` but I don't want it to have a preceding `0` so I use the singular `H`

Comment: @Noobster thank you, maybe this site may help you in future https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Toshi thank you too. The problem that I don't want to browse too much in the msdn website is that because for me it looks so complex for a beginner in c#.